# Randomizing predictions with ARIMA model

Tags: python, statistics, forecasting, arima

I made a synthetic data generator with the SARIMA model based on an input sample. The SARIMA model predicts time series of the length of the original input and I must say that it works quite well. I wonder if there is a way to get n number of time series similar to the predicted time series using this model.

Comment: Of course there is. Just use your model in a recursive fashion. Regarding the AR part of your model, start with values at t=0, and then produce your [t=1]-values from [t=0]'s, your [t=2]-values from [t=1]'s, etc... Regarding the MA part, you will have to deal with a backshift operator, reverse it, and make it work on your [t=t'-1] residuals. Regarding the seasonality, do not hesitate to provide us with more details.

Comment: This question belongs to https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think I don't understand it. I used pmdarima package with autoarima that offers gridsearch for hiperparameters.